# Get logs from kafka and send to loki

Tags: kubernetes, logging, apache-kafka, fluentd, grafana-loki

hope you're all well during this pandemic.

I've got a kubernetes cluster running. The comunication between pods is done through kafka. It is currently logging to stdout only. No files. no kafka topic. This is obviously pretty bad.

I want to setup a grafana instance that lets me centralize all logs there. The storage would be Loki + S3

In order to do that, I found that many people use tools like Fluentd, FluentBit and Promtail, which centralizes the logs and sends them to Loki. However, I already have Kafka running. I can't see why I'd use some tool like fluentd if I can send all logs to kafka through a "logging" topic.

My question is: How could I send all messages inside the logging topic to Loki? Fluentd cannot get input from kafka.

Would I have to setup some script that runs periodically, sorts data and sends it to loki directly?

Comment: Are you saying that you should be able to log directly into Kafka instead of stdout? I'm not sure Docker/Kubernetes supports that... You'd need to use fluentd to get data into Kafka, if that's what you wanted, but after that, you'd need a Kafka consumer to write to Loki, so Kafka is only acting as a buffer

Comment: well it must support it, no? I'd just need to add a handler to my logger (python app). I must not be seeing something. My ideia currently is to log directly to kafka through python, make a consumer and run it inside fluentd using the "in_exec" plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use promtail because is also from Grafana and not use the kafka solution.

If you send the logs from your apps to kafka then you need to:

- modify your apps to send to kafka instead of stdout
- configure a log forwarder to send messages on kafka to loki (it can be fluentd)

And if you use one the normal proposed approach you need to:

- configure a log forwarder to send messages from docker stdout to loki (you can use promtail default configuration)

But if you want to go for your solution with kafka in the middle there are some plugins of fluentd to configure kafka as input and output. https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka